# Is it possible to build round bar chart with Zingchart?

Tags: zingchart

Is it possible to build a round bar chart or radial bar chart with zingchart. Something like this.
[Apexchart](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/radialbar-charts/custom-angle-circle/)

Comment: I dont think you can do it with ZingChart , but ChartJS contains radial bars

Comment: @KaramMohamed Ok thanks

Answer (score 0):

While you can technically build all charts in ZingChart because we are just a rendering engine, this chart type bodes itself more difficult to render than most. We have examples on the site:

[Demo 1](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/spotify-usage-demo)

[image]

[Demo 2](https://www.zingchart.com/gallery/pie-chart-with-custom-animation)

[image]